# Как скачать файл с сервера

Tags: delphi, клиент-сервер

Добрый день! Клиентом подключаюсь к серверу, передаю название файла, путь куда скачать файл и передаю сервером этот файл клиенту через тсп. Теперь возник вопрос как тоже самое сделать только через url.
Вот проекты http://rgho.st/8RRsrCYPx

Серверная часть:(В настройках сервера указан порт и ip)

```
procedure TServerForm.BtStartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Activity:=not Activity;
   if Activity=true then
   begin
      BtStart.Caption:='Стоп';
      MyHTTPServer.Active:=True;
   end
   else
   begin
      BtStart.Caption:='Старт';
      MyHTTPServer.Active:=False;
   end;
end;
procedure TServerForm.MyHTTPServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
   MessageDlg('1111111', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
   AResponseInfo.ContentStream:=TFileStream.Create('d:/work/11.txt',fmOpenRead);
end;
```

Клиентская часть:

```
begin
   MyHTTPClient.BoundIP:=EdHost.Text;
   MyHTTPClient.BoundPort:=strtoint(EdPort.Text);
   try
      MyHTTPClient.Connect;
   except
      MessageDlg('Не удается соединиться с сервером', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
      Exit;
   end;

   stream:=TFileStream.Create(EdSavepath.Text, fmCreate);
   ForceDirectories(ExtractFileDir(EdSavepath.Text));
   try
      MyHTTPClient.Get(EdSend.Text,stream);
   finally
      MyHTTPClient.Free;
      stream.Free;
   end;
```

Comment: Постарайтесь предоставить [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Victor постарался вытащить суть

Comment: «то же самое, только через url» — требует расшифровки. что именно «то же самое»? каким образом «то же самое» связано с «url»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin успокойся, сделал я уже